# React indexOf undefined inside filter method

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am testing out react by building this simple app that takes an array of objects and filters them based on a search.

I am using JSON placeholder posts as *backend*

This is the code that gets the data from JSON placeholder

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios('/api/posts/')
    .then(res => this.setState({ posts: res.data}))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
};
```

And this is the code that filter

```
let filterdPosts = this.state.posts.filter(post => {
    return post.author.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
})
```

`this.state.search` is just a string with the search value

lastly, this is the error react gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

In one or more of your posts object within state, author is undefined and hence you get that error.

You could add a conditional check like

```
let filterdPosts = this.state.posts.filter(post => {
    return post.author && post.author.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use indexing of a string, you have to convert it into an array.

Comment: Thanks but Shubham Khatri fixed my problem there was a small but in the data I got. One of the objects was missing the author field